# Linking a dir to stdin

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I know under Unix there was a way to link a directory to the standard input of a program.
In such a way that when you drop a file into this directory, the OS would start a program and use this file as standard input.

Basicly how email lists worked in the old days.

And how would you do the same trick under Windows if posible?

Comment: The Linux interface for detecting changes to the file system is [inotify](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rml/inotify/README), but it doesn't work by "connecting a directory to stdin". Note that inotify does only work for *local* mounts (i.e., doesn't work for NFS mounts).

Answer (score 0):

Under windows, you can take a look at `Directory Change Notifications`. The following links might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx